# Escaping spaces in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why in some cases it's ok to have spaces in parameters and in some cases it's not.

In this example it's ok to have spaces in `$file` variable, but not in `$path`.

```
$file = "test file.tar"
$path = "a b\"
New-Item -Path $path -Type Directory
# Make an empty tar file
tar -cf $file -T NUL
# extract it to $path
tar -xf $file -C $path
```

Gives you

```
tar.exe: could not chdir to 'a b"'
```

And most bizarre

```
tar -xf $file -C `"$path
```

works just fine.

I'm on Windows 11 and using the default PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: You're seeing a Windows PowerShell bug that has since been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+: a string with spaces that ends in ``\`` is incorrectly passed to external programs in that the necessary _escaping_ as ``\\`` in the - of necessity - double-quoted string that is used behind the scenes isn't performed.
See the linked duplicate for details.